# How to find the dot proudct of 2 different vectors?

Tags: c, dot-product

```
/* dot_product(n, V1, V2)
 Given an integer n and two n-element vectors V1 and V2, compute and return
 the dot product of V1 and V2.

 Do not modify any elements of the input vectors V1 and V2.

 Parameters: n (integer), V1 (array of double), V2 (array of double)
 Return value (double): Dot product of V1 and V2
 */
 double dot_product(int n, double V1[n], double V2[n]);
```

I have a double V1[] = {-0.5, 0.5}; and double V2[] = {9, -9, 1}; but they have different number. Anyone know how to put into c code?

Comment: So you want to compute the dot product of V1 and V2 ... even though V1 and V2 have a different number of terms?  You're saying V1 has two terms, and V2 three?

Comment: yes i want to...

Comment: The dot product is only defined mathematically for vectors of the same length.

Answer (score 0):

> How to find the dot product of 2 different vectors?

**Pseudo-code answer**

Referencing [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product),

- Form the initial sum

  ```
    sum = 0
  ```
- Loop and add each product:

  ```
    for each i: 0 to n-1
       sum = sum + V1[i] * V2[i]
  ```
- Return result

  ```
    return sum
  ```

---

> I have a `double V1[] = {-0.5, 0.5};` and `double V2[] = {9, -9, 1};`

The given is in error as the length of both arrays is expected to be the same for a dot product.  Re-check your sources.

`double dot_product(int n, double V1[n], double V2[n]);` implies both arrays have the **same** length `n`.

---

A possible result to the below when `n1 != n2`:

```
double dot_product(int n1, double V1[n1], int n2, double V2[n2]);
```

is [not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) to reflect an error in the inputs.

```
double dot_product(int n1, double V1[n1], int n2, double V2[n2]) {
  if (n1 != n2 || n1 < 0) {
    return NAN;
  }
  ...
}
```